# Targeting variables for pluralisation with javascript -

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an integration of the search tool algolia within one of my projects. I have the following lines of code (with dummy variables added for completeness):

```js
var nbHits = 1
var processingTimeMS = 200

$('#hits-stat').html('<div class="float-right p-3">Found <b>' +
            nbHits + '</b> results in <b>' + processingTimeMS + '</b>ms. ' +
            'Powered by Algolia</div>'
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="hits-stat">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is an easy way to target the "**results**" in the element above and make it pluralised, e.g., for `let nbHits = 1` I want this to read "result". Is there such a method that would take up approx 3/4 lines of code maximum such that I am not adding too many kb's to my script? I've seen a few examples which are adding approx 20kbs.

I'm sure I should be using React/Vue but I'm still jQuerying my life away :'(

Comment: Write a function that takes in a string, and based on that number param,  pluralize it

Comment: Use ternary expressions: `$('#hits-stat').html('<div class="float-right p-3">Found <b>' +
            nbHits + '</b> result' + nbHits === 1 ? '' : 's' + 'in <b>' + processingTimeMS + '</b>ms. ' +
            'Powered by Algolia</div>'
        );`

Comment: @SterlingArcher That would be a huge task to do. Pluralize child. Pluralize information. Pluralize car. Pluralize sheep.

Comment: You could also pass it the singular and plural. ternaries get messy

Comment: I knew this question would receive negative feedback but it would be nice if we had a solution for *ANY* word, e.g., child -> children etc etc

Comment: This would obviously need dictionaries with all the non-standard pluralization cases listed. So no way can this ever be 3-4 lines of code. Ternary expressions are probably your best bet here, since you're still stuck on jQuery anyway.

Comment: I read this as for special case. If you want computational linguistics, I think you're on the wrong overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#hits-stat').html('<div class="float-right p-3">Found <b>' +
    nbHits + `</b> result${nbHits==1 ? '' : 's'} in <b>` + processingTimeMS + '</b>ms. ' +
    'Powered by Algolia</div>'
);
```

Comment: Sure OP's browser supports template literals? If they are still using jQuery, chances are they never made contact with tools like Babel.

Comment: @connexo What does using jQuery have to do with the browser version? People don't use jQuery just to support old browsers, they use it because it makes Javascript programming easier.

Comment: I'm not referring to jQuery, I'm referring to your use of template literals. If you're even aware you used template literals, that is. No version of Internet Explorer supports template literals.

Comment: It's easier to reply as a template literal, and not hard to convert to strings + logic if one is still in the stone age.

Comment: IE11 is not stone age. Definitely not.

Comment: Um, yeah it is. Sorry that this was already in the comments BTW... overflow sends when a new answer is posted when writing an answer, but nt comments. That slipped in while I was reading the OP and writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statement inside .html() like so:

```js
$('#hits-stat').html('<div class="float-right p-3">Found <b>' +
            nbHits + (nbHits > 1 ? '</b> results in <b>' : '</b> result in <b>')+ processingTimeMS + '</b>ms. ' +
            'Powered by Algolia</div>'
        );
```

Comment: This was already in the comments, in a more concise version. Also you ignore the case `nbHits === 0` (where it has to be plural, too).